# 1 to 100 odd numbers in array

Tags: ruby

Is there any cool way in Ruby to create an array with 1 to 100 with only odd entries (1, 3 etc). I now have a loop for this but that is obviously not a cool way to do it! Any suggestions?

My current code:

```
def create_1_to_100_odd_array
    array = [1]
    i = 3
    while i < 100
        array.push i
        i += 2
    end

    array
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step) class comes with a very cool feature for that purpose:

```
1.9.3-p286 :005 > (1..10).step(2).to_a
 => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great and simple answer!

Answer (score 15):

May not be efficient, but a short piece of code:

```
(1..100).select(&:odd?)

# => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```

Comment: I don't think "a short code" is valid English. I think that "a short piece of code" would work better.

Answer (score 5):

Just toying...

```
(0...50).map(&:object_id)
#or
1.step(100,2).to_a
```

Comment: The first one is too technical and is not a rubyish way. It is not beautiful. If I were to go along that line, I would do `map{|i| 2*i+1}`. The second one is good.

Comment: @sawa The first one is a joke, probably a bad one.

Comment: The OP asked for a cool way, not necessarily a maintainable or beautiful way!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I think cool is close to beautiful in this context. What is the difference?

Comment: @sawa I'd regard "cool" in this context as being somewhat similar to "awesome". Wiktionary gives translations of it into Japanese as クール, 素敵 and すごい, and in this context, it'd match [すごい](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%99%E3%81%94%E3%81%84&eng=&dict=edict) (amazing, great) better than [クール](http://jisho.org/words?jap=+%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB&eng=&dict=edict) ("cool (i.e. fashionable, attractive, etc.)" and [素敵](http://jisho.org/words?jap=+%E7%B4%A0%E6%95%B5&eng=&dict=edict) ("lovely; dreamy; beautiful; great; fantastic; superb; cool; capital")

Answer (score 3):

Since you need a function, then:

```
def odd_to(n)
    (1..n).step(2).to_a
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very effective solution, but quite elegant:

```
(1..100).select {|a| a%2 != 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as a one-liner when you instantiate the array:

```
def create_array_of_odds_to(n)
  Array.new((n + 1) / 2) {|i| 2 * i + 1}
end

create_array_of_odds_to 10   # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```