# can instances of a super class communicate with each other just as instances of a normal class

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Instances of a class can access methods of other instances, but is it possible to do this for two distinct subclasses of a class with different methods? Or must the methods accessed be included in the super class?

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Comment: okay so i have a deck class  which provides a get_hand method and i have a number of hand class instances which need to  use this class instance to  determine there hands randomly ! My own approach to this  caused circularity problems !

Comment: Exactly why do you need to use subclasses for this?  You should need Deck, Hand, Card classes at maximum.  Most likely you can get away with less than that and use Arrays or Hashes to fill in the rest...

Comment: [This](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2009/10/26/goodbye-simplicity-im-object-obsessed/) article comes to mind...

Comment: Thank you i will read this ! It's i past exam question  for a module I'm taking based around object orientation and the question seems to describe some kind of relation between the two classes such as this

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I didn't type "English grammer". It comes from Cleanshooter's edit. I accepted it with modification. The edit title was automatically inherited.

Comment: @sawa <insert object oriented joke about inheritance here>

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I was thinking of sending you a message right before I passed you last night, but I thought you were observing anyway.

Comment: @sawa are you referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550042/ruby-1-to-100-odd-numbers-in-array/13550851#comment18577232_13550851 , or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to keep track of your associations by passing in the Deck instance     to the individual Hand instances.  Here is an example based on the scenario you described:

```
class Card
   attr_accessor :suit, :value

  def initialize(suit, value)
    @suit = suit
    @value = value
  end
end

class Deck
  SUITS = ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]
  VALUES = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
  HAND_SIZE = 5

  attr_accessor :cards

  def initialize
    shuffle
  end

  def shuffle
    @cards = []
    SUITS.each do |suit|
      VALUES.each do |value|
        @cards << Card.new(suit, value)
      end
    end
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def deal_hand
    shuffle if @cards.size < (HAND_SIZE + 1)
    hand = @cards[0...HAND_SIZE]
    @cards = @cards.drop(HAND_SIZE)
    hand
  end
end

class Player
  attr_accessor :deck
  attr_accessor :hand

  def initialize(deck)
    @deck = deck
  end

  def draw!
    @hand = @deck.deal_hand
  end
end

# initialize
the_deck = Deck.new
players = []
players << (player1 = Player.new(the_deck))
players << (player2 = Player.new(the_deck))
players << (player3 = Player.new(the_deck))
players << (player4 = Player.new(the_deck))

# draw
players.each do |player|
  player.draw!
end

# play
# ...
```

Hope this helps.